# How commit tree would look like in Integration-Manager Workflow?

Tags: git, workflow, integration

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

> One of the main advantages of this approach is that you can continue
>   to work, and the maintainer of the main repository can pull in your
>   changes at any time. Contributors don’t have to wait for the project
>   to incorporate their changes — each party can work at their own pace.

I made a picture showing how I think it would work, IS THAT correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphs do show a possible work-flow.  It would be more typical, however, for the maintainer to merge in dev A's work to `maintainer` first, then merge dev B's work, or vice versa, at step 4, creating two separate merges that look more like:

```
o     o
|  o  |
| /|  |
|/ |  |
o  |  o
|  |  |
o  |  o
|  |  |
o  |  o
 \ | /
  \|/
   o
```

followed by:

```
   o
   |\
   | \
o  |  o
|  o  |
| /|  |
|/ |  |
o  |  o
|  |  |
o  |  o
|  |  |
o  |  o
 \ | /
  \|/
   o
```

at step 4.  Alternatively, if the maintainer is something of a Git guru, they could use a so-called *octopus merge* to keep the middle "maintainer" path as the main line, so that there is only one merge but it looks like this:

```
o     o
|  o  |
| /|\ |
|/ | \|
o  |  o
|  |  |
o  |  o
|  |  |
o  |  o
 \ | /
  \|/
   o
```

with the first parent of the middle column commit being the bottom-most commit in the drawing.

Comment: But i thought that you should always delete a branch after merging it to the master branch. In THAT case, you are merging master branch to another branch multiple times? Sorry but, i didn't know that it was allowed!

Comment: There's no requirement to delete a branch after merging, though if you use Git's so-called "squash merge" (which isn't a merge—it does the verb, *to merge*, but not the noun/adjective *a merge* or *a merge commit*) it *is* a good idea to stop using, and eventually delete, that branch. Of course various work-flows have specific additional requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but, what would happen if a conflict occur? Both devs would not be able to update their branches! they must stop their work, merge the last commit on both branches, solve the conflict and THEN continue their work?

Comment: As a general rule, things work better if you have the developer do the merge himself or herself anyway. After all, it's the developer who made the change and knows what it's supposed to do and how the change achieves that result. If there is a merge conflict, the same developer can and probably should fix it. Web sites like GitHub make this a bit more difficult if pull requests must be merged by an administrator, but if you are using a private setup, you can have that happen.

Comment: One compromise approach, when a maintainer must do the merge, is for a developer to do a *test merge*, make sure it is all good, and only then notify the maintainer. If the maintainer has already merged someone else's work, the maintainer tells the developer, who fetches, rebases or re-merges as needed, and then re-notifies the maintainer. This flow works with GitHub style "only maintainer may merge to master" setups.

Comment: Okay! I really appreciate your help! Thank you!